# Complie Error: Method or Data Member not found, but it does exist

Tags: ms-access, vba

Having a strange problem in vba access. I have a text control control called txtUserName on a form and am trying to get the contents which is all but child's play. When I try to run or complie, I get the Method or Data Member not found error. However, when I type me. Intellisense shows txtUserName. I have gone as far as copying and pasting the name from the control's properties and still get the error. What am I missing? I am completely perplexed.

Thanks in advance
Don

Comment: You might want to post your code.

Comment: In this case, I was just building a SQL string. I did find the problem, there was a bad control reference, however, it was not the one that was highlighted (highlighted was the first value in an insert into string and it was actually the 3rd value). Thanks Rdster for the suggestion of posting the code that is how I found it!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I was just building a SQL string. I did find the problem, there was a bad control reference, however, it was not the one that was highlighted (highlighted was the first value in an insert into string and it was actually the 3rd value)